# SQL Converting strings to date

Tags: sql, date

this has really baffled me for a few days and am seeking help. I am using SQL Server 2017.

I am trying to handle strings from a free format field and either convert them to a date in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy" or if they are not in this format then simply display the text verbatim.

I need this in a VIEW so can not use SET LANGUAGE. Sounds simple using **convert** and **isdate** but does not seem to work.

So for the snippet of code below (remember this will be in a VIEW) I want to read the text and if the string converts to a date (ie. is in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy" then run the convert to a date as I need it in date format for Excel to pick up (via Connect SQL Sever Database)), and if it does not convert to a date then display the text as it is.

```
create table dateTest1 
( idx int, 
 dateStringTest varchar(15) 
); 
  
insert into dateTest1 (idx, dateStringTest) 
values (1, '13/01/2021'), (2, 'no'); 
 
 
select 
       case when isdate(convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103)) = 1 
       then convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103)
       else dateStringTest 
       end as dtres
from dateTest1 
--where idx = 1 
  
-- error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. 
-- this error happens for idx = 2. Idx = 1 works ok
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated as it's doing my head in.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well suited your database is to doing this.  The data conversion functions in SQL Server are a bit "clumsy", compared to some others.

However, from your database's point of view:

If something is *supposed* to be a **Date**, then it *should be* a date.
It might be "missing" (i.e. nullable) but it can't be anything else.
If it *were* to be anything else, then it should not be treated *as* a **Date**.

Users cannot enter **Dates** - only the *Character Representations* of them.
Displaying [numbers and] dates from your application requires formatting on the "way out".
Reading [numbers and] dates into your application requires the reverse, "un-formatting" (and validation, of course) on the "way in".
Data should *always* be stored in the *correct* Data Type - "The Right Tool for the Right Job".

Free-text parsing is *probably* best done in your application, extracting the date value, validating and "un-formatting" it and then storing it.

Comment: Please try to avoid answering off-topic questions.

Comment: Answering the question is one thing.  Guiding the poster to question the question can often be better because they may be trying to solve the /wrong/ problem.  I do not regard guiding people away from [frankly] Bad Practices that /will/ come back and bite them later as "off topic".  Date handling is hard enough as it is when you know you're working with a date.  Adding ifs and buts and maybes about whether what you're looking is a date or not will drive you and your database to madness.